# Python: Checking for directories in CVS Repository

Tags: python, repository, cvs, directory-structure

I'm wondering if I could use

```
os.path.isdir(sourceDirectory)
```

to check for the existence of a directory in a CVS repository.  Similarly, if the os.walk method would work for a repository directory.  If not, what would be a good way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

os handles this very well already! Isn't python wonderful?
The following example searches for a file named CSV in the root directory of your machine, but you can point it to any directory you like, including a relative path.

```
def file_exists():
   path = '/' # the path you want to search for the file in
   target = 'CSV' # name of the directory
   if target in os.list:
      #do whatever you were going to do once you confirmed that this file exists
      return True
   return False
```

Comment: Thanks, this isn't quite what I was looking for, but I think the basis of my question didn't really make sense.  If I do a quick temporary checkout of directory in CVS (Concurrent Versions System) repository, I get a working copy of it locally and obviously os modules will work as expected.  I can then remove the temporary directory.